# How come I am unable to delete elements from my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

[image: The List]
This is a list that the user has made, and the destroy method in the Tracks controller (Each track refers to each element in the list) deletes them once the link is clicked. However, this does happen, and the list stays constant.

The Controller:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
def index
    @track = Track.new
    @tracks = Track.all
end

def create 
    @track = Track.new(params[:track])
    if @track.save
        redirect_to :action=>"index"
    else 
    @tracks = Track.all
    render :action=>"index"
    end
end

def destroy
    @track = Track.find(params[:id])
    @track.destroy
    redirect_to(tracks_url)
end
end
```

The Template (To refer to the line that creates the delete link and defines its behaviour)

```
<h1>Playlist</h1>

<%= form_for @track,:url=>{:action=>'create'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :youtube_url, :required=>true %>
        <%= f.submit 'Add' %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<hr />

<% if Track.first == nil %>
<p>Database is empty!</p>
<%else%>
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
  <ul class="list_container">
    <li class="list_elements"><i class="bullet icon-asterisk"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= track.youtube_url %></li><i class="icon-remove-circle remove_pos"><%=link_to 'delete', :controller=>"tracks", :method=>:delete,:id=>track.id %></i>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

[image: And finally the routes.rb that seems to be intact.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using

```
resources :tracks
```

in your routes.rb file, then the controller action you want is destroy, not delete. So change that method name there.

```
def destroy
  @track = Track.find(params[:id])
  @track.destroy
  redirect_to(tracks_url)
end
```

Then in your view, the :method parameter is the HTTP verb DELETE, so that bit becomes

```
<li class="list_elements"><i class="bullet icon-asterisk"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= track.youtube_url %></li><i class="icon-remove-circle remove_pos"><%=link_to 'delete', :controller => "tracks", :method => :delete, :id => track.id %></i>
```

Comment: I tried this, again, the list stays constant...

Answer (score 2):

Your method should be `delete`, not `destroy`. The HTTP verbs you are interested in are `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`; Rails will map `DELETE` requests (via resourceful routes) to `destroy` actions, but you don't specify `destroy` as the verb.

Comment: Sorry that was something I changed just to see if that was the problem, thank you for that though. Changing the method to delete does not effectively make the program react differently either.

Comment: Changing code to show what it should look like so you can clarify